# Detecting the WM_CLOSE event on main application window when a modal dialog is active?

Tags: c++, c, windows, modal-dialog, window-messages

Is it possible for the the main application window to detect a WM_CLOSE event when a modal dialog is active?. If not, is there any way of detecting the WM_CLOSE event because the event handler for the dialog does not detect it either.

To observe this behaviour for yourself, open the 'about' menu of notepad and then right-click on the notepad icon in the taskbar and select the 'close window' option, it will have no effect.

Does anyone know of  a way to catch a WM_CLOSE event for an application when a modal window is active?

Comment: I would think none is sent while it's disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows MessageBox ignoring WM\_QUIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427103/windows-messagebox-ignoring-wm-quit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When selecting "close" by right-clicking an application's icon in the task bar no `WM_CLOSE` is sent.

What happens is that the application's main window is sent a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with `wParam` set to `SC_CLOSE`.

For an example on how to exploit this "feature" please [see my other answer on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17433376/694576).